# How to force stopwatch - start/stop from label1.text?

Tags: c#, asp.net, stopwatch

I am practicing a small project. According to mouse movements, the stop watch has to be started or stop.
ie, once the mouse is inside  then start the stopwatch otherwise stop. Is it possible?

my codes: aspx page

```
<div id="Divn1" onmousemove="MyNewFunction(event)" onmouseout="ClearCoor()" style="width:99%; height:99%; border:solid;background-color:white; position:absolute;">
            <p id="Demo1"></p>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Size="XX-Large"></asp:Label>
            <div id="Divn2" style="width:50px;height:50px;border-radius:50%;background-color:brown; position:absolute; top:45%; margin-left:47%;">

            </div>
           <asp:scriptmanager ID="Scriptmanager1" runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
              <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Size="XX-Large"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Timer ID="tm1" Interval="1000" runat="server" ontick="tm1_Tick" />
              </ContentTemplate>
              <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tm1" EventName="Tick" />
              </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

        </div>
```

And then aspx.cs

```
    public static Stopwatch sw;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
        }
    }
    protected void tm1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        long milsecs = sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds;
        if (Label2.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("00:ff");
        }
        sw.Stop();
        //Label1.Visible = false;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Timer and stop watch are not the thing you can use in web application for interactive UI in asp.net. Can you elaborate on the use case you want to implement?

Comment: can u post any sample of codings? thanks . Iam looking to count my mouse, speed of rotation on the screen but only for clock wise rotation & not for anti-clock rotation.. Thanks